# C# Ajax Get Request

Tags: c#, ajax, httpwebrequest

Hello so I'm trying to get the reply from 
https://www.epicgames.com/payment/ajaxGetOrderHistory?
I have a working code but it's in Python,

```
 headers = {
                    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, "
                                  "like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36",
                    'Host': "www.epicgames.com",
                    'Pragma': "no-cache",
                    'Connection': "keep-alive",
                    'Referer': "https://www.epicgames.com/account/payment/history",
                    'Keep-Alive': "true",
                    'x-requested-with': "XMLHttpRequest",

                    'Cache-Control': "no-cache"
                }
                full_info = sesion.get('https://www.epicgames.com/payment/ajaxGetOrderHistory?', headers=headers,
                                       proxies=proxy, timeout=10)
```

Now I'm coding something in c# but it isn't quite working as I want it to :(

```
httpRequest.AddHeader("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");
            string input = httpRequest.Get("https://www.epicgames.com/payment/ajaxGetOrderHistory?", null).ToString();
```

I tried that but it returned me a "401" saying it was an error on the client side, Now I've tried to add the same headers of the Python code but no result either. The website itself doesn't return anything either but i know from using the Python code that it works

Anyone knows a solution? thanks!

Comment: You are getting 401 Unauthorised. Are you passing credentials somewhere in your code?

Comment: @derloopkat i think I do trough cookies yes

Comment: For starters add same headers. If it doesn't work and you have a code that works in Python I suggest to run it, capture a successful request and compare it to the one that doesn't work. You need to be able to generate same request in C#. So first thing is to find out what's missing.

Comment: @derloopkat How would i capture it tho?

Comment: Use your browser's inspection tool (network tab) or install Fiddler. Are you passing cookies in C# code?

Comment: @derloopkat tried for hours, no result

Comment: Please update your question with latest C# code including those headers. In your Python code you're using a proxy but there's no proxy in your C# version. However we have no way to test that without credentials.